# Win32Com: Add a new Excel file and save as .xlsm

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am using Win32com in Python.

Basically I want to create a new .xlsm workbook.

**1) But SaveAs doesn't work for me, I always encounter the below error**

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\\//Users/~/322DF100'. There are several possible reasons:\n\n• The file name or path does not exist.\n• The file is being used by another program.\n• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

import win32com.client as w3c
xl=w3c.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
xl.DisplayAlerts=False


wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
wb.SaveAs ('C:/Users/~/OUTPUT8.xlsm')
wb.Close(SaveChanges=False)

del wb
xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
```

**2) SaveCopyAs works, but I can't open the file**
**Excel cannot open the file because the file format or extension is not valid.**

```
import win32com.client as w3c
xl=w3c.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
xl.DisplayAlerts=False


wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
wb.SaveCopyAs ('C:/Users/~/OUTPUT8.xlsm')
wb.Close(SaveChanges=False)

del wb
xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
```

Comment: The first problem seems to be related to slashes/backslashes. Try to use backslashes in the path.

Comment: As @Michael O. says, you may have a backslash issue try using '\\'. The SaveCopyAs 'seems' to work because you have set 'DisplayAlerts' to False, so the error is being suppressed. With SaveAs the code can't carry on because now the current workbook has an invalid path.

Comment: @ Michael O.: SaveAS worked when I changed to double backslash. But in general how do I know if I should use forward slash or double backslash? Thanks!